# Unable to install CUDA toolkit on ubuntu 18.04 LTS . Stuck at waiting for headers at 99%

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I'm trying to install tensorflow-gpu on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have an ASUS GL553VD with NVIDIA GTX-1050. I'm following the installation instructions for CUDA 9.0 as seen here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal

Everything works fine until I run `sudo apt-get install cuda` (i.e. the 4th step) and then this happens:[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIVOl.png)

I have been following this tutorial to install tensorflow-gpu: https://github.com/markjay4k/Install-Tensorflow-on-Ubuntu-17.10-/blob/master/Tensorflow%20Install%20instructions.ipynb

I've tried changing mirrors a lot, selecting the best Ubuntu finds as well as others. I've run `sudo apt-get update` multiple times **successfully**. but installation for CUDA always gets stuck at Waiting for headers:99% and then aborts installation.

Please tell me how can I get this to work or please tell me any other configurations of GPU drivers, CUDA and cuDNN that Tensorflow supports. I have trying to install CUDA 9.0 since its mentioned on the official website: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: The graphics-drivers ppa is (trying) to bring in the 390.87 driver -- maybe get rid of that ppa , clean out any (partially) installed nvidia drivers, and just use the standard repo to get the 390.77 driver.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have resolved your issue, i faced a similar issue when running `sudo apt-get install cuda` with similar error message of `99% Waiting for header`

```
E: Failed to fetch http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/./cuda-cupti-10-1_10.1.168-1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 192.229.232.112 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

All i did was repeatedly running `sudo apt-get install cuda --fix-missing` until the installation continued to fix the issue.

Hope this helps whoever who would potentially meet the same issue :)